# Python data extraction : How to apply all the variables in the 'For Loop' to 'data frame.column.'

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I would like to divide the DataFrame Based on the unique values of a particular column in the data frame. Before dividing the data frame, I made the list variable that applies it.

```
list1 = [a,b,c,d]
for name in list1[:]:
   Data = df.loc[(df['column_name'] == name)]
```

this code, only the last value of 'd' applies.
How can I apply all the list1_variables through For Loop?
On the other hand, Please let me know if there is a better way than For Loop!

Comment: `Data` holds only one subset of your `df` at a time. You could just do `{n: df[df["column_name"].eq(n)] for n in list1}` to get a dictionary of dataframes.

Comment: What do you want to do with `Data`? If you want to split the dataframe into multiple dataframes, you can follow what @not_speshal recommended. It sounds like you're wanting to store `Data` to be referenced by some future code, so you need to determine who you want that stored.

Answer (score 0):

As I posted in my comment to your question, it depends on what you ultimately want to do with `Data`. Following the code you've posted, I've included an example where `Data` is a list of dictionaries.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'a': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
    'b': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = []
for name in df['a'].unique():
    data.append(
        {name: [i for i in df.loc[(df['a'] == name)]['b']]}
    )

print(data)
```